# Spring boot build error after adding jpa depencency

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using parent dependency as

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

with JPA dependency I am getting following error:

> ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered
>   during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSource' parameter
>   0; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'spring.datasource-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties':
>   Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties]:
>   Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/dao/DataAccessException

The error vanishes after I remove spring-boot-starter-data-jpa dependency the project builds from `pom.xml` the project compiles.

The project was working until today, but after a Java update I am getting this error.

UPDATE: I have only one hello restcontroller in the app which returns simple string

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**and error while starting app**

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-01-15 11:28:36.148 ERROR 8764 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSource' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.datasource-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/dao/DataAccessException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1134) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1028) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at com.example.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.datasource-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/dao/DataAccessException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1116) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1060) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1136) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1064) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/dao/DataAccessException
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:154) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1108) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/dao/DataAccessException
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.<init>(DataSourceProperties.java:153) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
```

Comment: share the pom.xml

Comment: Are you using data source autoconfiguration ? . Can you share the datasource config ?

Comment: I am not using any data source , I just added jpa dependency and run....and have the error.... This is some thing crazey

Comment: you have derby db runtime, comment it out(if you are not using). also exclude autoconfiguration like @SpringBootApplication(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})

Comment: Hi Barath, I will be using in memory Derby db hence, i understand jpa will be auto configured to derby db.

Comment: ok that means you have a Bean of EmbeddedDataBase type ? @Bean
 public DataSource dataSource() {

  
  EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
  EmbeddedDatabase db = builder
   .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.DERBY) 
   .build();
  return db;
 }

Answer (score 2):

When you add spring-boot-starter-data-jpa, Spring Boot looks for datasource properties, so that it can connect to the database.

You need to add the following properties to application.properties (change values as per the DB configuration on your machine)

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
spring.datasource.username=dbuser
spring.datasource.password=dbpass
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

In case you want to test (or play around with) spring-data-jpa, use following in-memory database dependency in your pom.xml. In this case, you dont need to add any properties, Spring Boot will **auto-configure** it for you.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

[Documentation link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html)

Comment: thanks for the reply, i still have issue after following your steps, it seems to be different issue which i am not able to get . i preferred adding in-memory db and here is the debug error  =========================
AUTO-CONFIGURATION REPORT
=========================


Positive matches:
-----------------

   AopAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy', 'org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect', 'org.aspectj.lang.reflect.Advice' (OnClassCondition) .......

Comment: can you please share entire error stack.. above comment does not have the root cause of the error

Comment: I have update the question with details, i have the issue once i add jpa dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue.
I deleted all repository from .m2 folder (c:/users/{USER}/.m2/repository)
then rebuild workspace... it works